# How to save taxes on revenue from Admob ads?

Tags: tax-deduction, germany, google

I'm a mobile developer currently living in Germany. My revenue is generated by online ads of Google/Admob. Since Google is based in Ireland, the revenue/service/value are also generated in Ireland.

The German tax rate for this kind of revenue can be up to 60% depending on the amount earned.

Is it possible to reduce that tax rate by some *legal* financial scheme like "double-Irish-Dutch sandwich"?
(In other words, is it possible to live in Germany, and still pay at most 10% taxes?)

Comment: Double Dutch-Irish no longer exists, both countries changed their laws.